# Definition of local system

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homology-cohomology, principal-bundles, local-systems

I am struggling to understand section 2.1., page 20, of [these notes](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/beem/papers/kontsevich_soibelman_deformation_theory_1.pdf) by Kontsevich and Soibelman. They read (my comments and questions are inserted in bold):

> *2.1.Local systems*
> Let $X$ be a topological space (say, a CW complex), $G$ a Lie group. We denote by $G^{\delta}$ the group $G$ equipped with the discrete topology. We will refer to $G^{\delta}$-bundles as "local systems". [**Are $G^{\delta}$-bundles the same as [principal $G^{\delta}$-bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle)?**].
> One can see three different descriptions of local systems.
>
> *A. Sheaf theoretic* A local system is given by a covering $U_i$ of $X$ by open sets, transition functions $\gamma_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\rightarrow G$ [**Is $\gamma_{ij}$ required to be continuous and if so with respect to which topology?**] which are locally constant and satisfy the $1$-cocycle condition $g_{ij}g_{jk}g_{ki}=id$ [**This should probably read $\gamma_{ij}\gamma_{jk}\gamma_{ki}$ and not $g_{ij}g_{jk}g_{ki}$?**]. Equivalence of local systems is given by a common refinements of two coverings and a family of maps to $G$ which conjugate one system of transition functions to the other.
>
> *B. Group theoretic.* Suppose that $X$ is connected. Then equivalence classes of local systems are in one-to-one correspondence with the equivalence classes of homomorphisms of the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ to $G$. (If $X$ is not connected, one can use the fundamental groupoid instead of the fundamental group.)

- How does this tie in with the definition of local system [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_system)? The definition looks similar, but not quite the same.
- How are definitions A and B equivalent?

References welcome.

Comment: Why don't you read Steenrod's book, he covers this material quite well and you do not have to deal with typos.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do you mean the paper *Homology with local coefficients* (1943)?

Comment: I mean "Topology of fiber bundles".

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you a lot! Kontsevich' local system in Steenrod's terminology is a *system of coordinate transformations in $X$ with values in $G$* (see Definition 3.1. on page 14. of your recommended book.) Is Steenrod's terminology still common today? Also, how is this definition related to sheaves?